# How would you simulate an AGV based assembly line?

Tags: anylogic

For my thesis I want to simulate an AGV based assembly line. So instead assembling the product on a conveyor the assembly takes place directly on AGVs. The assembly line consists of several cycles. Depending on the products attributes (read in by database) the time at each cycle differs. The products assembly is taking place manually (2 workers in each cycle).

My goal is to see the impact of different cycle times, different sequences and so on.

Should I use the AGV Fleet for generating the AGVS and a product source or is it smarter to build the AGV as agents so you get two serparte sources (one for product, one for AGVs)?
In case of second suggestion is it possible to transport an agent with another agent?

I think the second suggestion is better to get more options for later Analytics right?

Furthermore I would like to know how to build the cycle. I only see palette blocks like "wait", "delay" or "station". I all these cases the AGV will stop for a certain amount of time. What I need is a "flowing" assembly without stopping. How would you implement that?

Thank you really much for helping me out and sacrificing your free time!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions on *how to solve a problem*, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is a generic “how do I best do X” question. This is too broad for SOF and better asked in a forum like LinkedIn. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions here: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Welcome again, we are all happy to help on specifics :)

Comment: Also check this about the AnyLogic community: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community